# video player with qt phonon (using python)

Tags: c++, python, qt, pyqt, phonon

I am working on Windows xp and am trying to get a simple video player running.

I am trying to use Phonon::VideoPlayer module for this. I am connecting the signal as

```
connect(self.player,SIGNAL("finished()"),self.player.deleteLater)
```

and then , when the Play button is pressed, it makes the following call:

```
self.player.play(Phonon.MediaSource("C:\\vid.mp4"))
```

But, this doesn't display the video in the video player widget. Neither can I hear audio. Can anyone help??

I tried using different video file formats but no luck.

Comment: if this is a signal / slot issue then you can tag this for QT and PYqt and ask the c++ crowd. if this is a pyqt/python thing, ask on irc.freenode.net #pyqt.

Comment: I don't think it is a signal slot issue. I am connecting the signal as per the documentation. Adding C++ keyword so that more people can notice.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing

```
self.player.play(Phonon.MediaSource("C:\\vid.mp4"))
```

to escape the `\`

Comment: actually, in my code, I am doing `os.path.normpath('C:\vid.mp4')`. So that is not the cause. (I didn't mention that to keep it simple, now updating the filepath)

Comment: @cppb: \v is not a proper character. use / or \\.

Answer (score 0):

```
Phonon::MediaSource mediaSource= Phonon::MediaSource("C:\\vid.mp4");
```

Try creating media sources like this and also other Phonon objects..