# Qt phonon video player example C++ or python

Tags: c++, qt, phonon

Does anyone have a working example of a **video player** built using Qt phonon? (in C++ )

See my related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454560/video-player-with-qt-phonon-using-python) . I am unable to build one using Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A working example of a video player built using Qt phonon: [Dragon Player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Player)

And here you find the Mplayer created with Phonen too, including all the sources: [Phonon MPlayer](http://code.google.com/p/phonon-vlc-mplayer/). You need to login, then you can browse the source code by clicking on "Source" and then "Browse".

**EDIT:** Oh, and of course the Media Player Example in the Qt Assistant, you should have a look at this, too. It plays both audio and video.

Answer (score 6):

I have written a Simple Video Player using QT. The soure of the player is also hardcoded for this example. See [here](http://twolinux.blogspot.com/2010/10/writing-simple-media-player-in-qt.html)

Answer (score 1):

Most qt and kde video players these days(not vlc).
  Looking for phonon reverse dependencies on ubuntu I find

- amarok(music player with videos
  support)
- minitube
- kmplayer
- bangarang
- dragonplayer

non video players

- okular(documents with embeded videos)
- web browsers w/html5 video I think

  - libqtwebkit4
  - libkonq5
  - ktorrent(I think torrent film previews)
  - gwenview(play videos in picture viewer?)
  - dolphin(file preview)