# How to play video using phonon

Tags: qt, phonon

I want to play video from my device . How can  i make it???

Can any help me??????

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt documentation:
[http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/phonon-overview.html](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/phonon-overview.html)

Similar question on StackOverflow:
[Qt phonon video player example C++ or python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463994/qt-phonon-video-player-example-c-or-python)

Comment: Yup, my answer to that question refers to the media player example in Qt Assistant. Definitely worth a look when learning to use phonon.