# WIth Qt,Video can play?

Tags: qt

I am new to the Qt software .
I want to know whether: with Qt coding ,Can I play and display video ??

If yes then which Qt API is required to do so ??

Comment: If you want to render a video, try to use SDL Library

Comment: I want to see the output of my object detection algorithm which is ported on DM8148 hardware with linux as file system .In this am not able to run the X server .SO want to use Qt to see the output video through HDMI output port .

Answer (score 1):

See in Qt Multimedia library (QMultimedia namespace), you can use [QVideoWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qvideowidget.html) control (since Qt 5.x.x) from this library

Comment: I am using Qt 4.6.2 version.So, Can I use above API ??

Comment: No, as it's said this API appreared in Qt5.

Comment: Ahswin, you can use the Phonon library - http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/phonon-overview.html. But in QT 4.x.x I prefer FFMpeg (in my experience...)

Answer (score 0):

In Qt 4.6.2 you may want to use [Phonon Module](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/phonon-module.html). Look at [VideoWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/phonon-videowidget.html). There is a simple example there.

Comment: It may be silly question to ask ,but I want to ask .I have the ouput generated with .avi extension . This output I want to play by using Qt .SO phonon module will help me in that ??

Comment: @ashwin Yes, it will help, but it also depends on codecs installed on your PC. You can see examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463994/qt-phonon-video-player-example-c-or-python)

Answer (score 0):

If you also have QtQuick cross-compiled for your platform, you can also use QML for presenting a video... I think it is the simplest solution, as you can see [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-videooutput.html)!